# Simple regex in Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs, glob

I have the following line in my `Gruntfile`.

`js
files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],`

Could someone be so kind as tell me what `{,*/}*` mean? I know it's trying to match all `.coffee` files in the scripts folder, but I want to know how it does that.

Comment: The [Grunt.js globbing patterns doc](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) gives some explanation as to what `{}` and `*` mean, but I'm still unable to put a complete explanation as to what the `{,*/}*` means.

Answer (score 16):

The `{,*/}` matches one or zero directories between scripts and the .coffee file. Inside the {} there are actually two matching terms separated by a comma. One is blank, represented by no characters to the left of the comma. One is any number of characters and a forward slash. The final * matches the filename before the .coffee extension.

By the way, this is not regular expressions, it's globbing.

Comment: Thank you. I am still unclear as to why the forward slash needs to be in the `{}`. What would something like this mean `{,*}/*`?

Comment: Hi Tri, the reason you need the / is that in globbing the * matches all characters EXCEPT an actual slash. It's set up that way so that, for example, globbing `/*/*/*` finds only files that are at a depth of two directories in your directory tree. `{,*}/*` would only match paths that do have a slash, where as `{,*/}*` makes the slash optional.

Comment: thanks for that your answer. That makes sense. However, if that's the case, why won't it be `{,*,/}*`, basically add another comma to separate the slash from the star?

Comment: I should have said " `{,*/}*` makes the directory and trailing slash for it optional" not just "makes the slash optional". If you do `{,*,/}*` then you are matching either: 1. nothing 2. some characters without a slash, which would have no effect because the * after the } would already allow these characters anyway 3. just a slash -- so it would only match `scripts//` which would be an odd path. You need `{,*/}*` so that you can match `scripts/anythinghere/file.coffee` or `scripts/file.coffee` . NB this does NOT match `scripts/anythinghere/somethingelsehere/file.coffee`.

Comment: I see. so you can sort of 'combine' `*/` together to mean any character including slash?

Comment: And your last point means that `{,*/}*` only works 1 level deep?

Comment: Yes to the previous comment, no to the comment before that. `*/` means "any character besides a slash, repeated any number of times, followed by a slash." The slash has to be at the end, because that's the order in the regex. It doesn't "combine".

Answer (score 6):

According to [the documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks):

> Also, because this is JavaScript, you're not limited to JSON; you may
>   use any valid JavaScript here. You may even programmatically generate
>   the configuration if necessary.

It looks like `{,*/}*` is a `JSON` match for:

```
{
 '' = empty space matches no character
 , = or
 * = Any Characters (except slash) (wildcard)
 / = literal slash
}
* = Any Characters (except slash) (wildcard)
```

**Update** [Found another resource](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns):

> **Globbing patterns**
>
> It is often impractical to specify all source filepaths individually,
>   so Grunt supports filename expansion (also know as globbing) via the
>   built-in node-glob and minimatch libraries.
>
> While this isn't a comprehensive tutorial on globbing patterns, know
>   that in a filepath:
>
> * matches any number of characters, but not /
>
> ? matches a single character, but not /
>
> ** matches any number of characters, including /, as long as it's the only thing in a path part
>
> {} allows for a comma-separated list of "or" expressions
>
> ! at the beginning of a pattern will negate the match

Comment: @SindreSorhus Do you have a resource that would show us what it means? It's funny I have a -1 and the other guy with the same answer has a +1. Was that you?

Comment: Hi Absolute... not sure what is up with Sindre -- our answers are indeed the same. I just upvoted yours.

Comment: I also just flagged Sindre's comment as not constructive.