# TypeDoc how to define externalPattern?

Tags: regex, typescript, gruntjs, documentation, typedoc

I'm working on app with grunt and typedoc.

I need to prepare documentation using TypeDoc but I have a problem with one scenario.

I have to exclude a few files from documentation which are externals libs.
I can't put those files into `exclude` section because those files are relating with another. If I tried to exclude it (by put those files into `exclude` section) I had a errors - something like `cannot find to xxx into yyy.ts` - where `xxx` is my excluded element and `yyy` is related file with `xxx`. Those 
 related files are neccessary on this documentation so I can't exclude those too.

I read into TypeDoc documentation about [excludeExternals](http://typedoc.org/api/classes/converter.html#excludeexternals). So I thought that if I set up this boolean as true then I can to define externalPattern to exclude my external files. It's works but only if I put the name of one file - no more.

Do You know how to do it?

It is my typedoc config into gruntfile.js (without excludeExternals options):

```
typedoc: {
    build: {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/',
            name: 'MyApp',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: [
                'node_modules',
                '**/*.d.ts'
            ],
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            ...some source...
        ]
    }
}
```

This is list of external files which I have to exclude: A.ts, B.ts, C.ts, D.ts ...

And this is my typedoc config into gruntfile.js (with excludeExternals options):

```
typedoc: {
    build: {
        options: {
            module: 'commonjs',
            out: '../Documentation/',
            name: 'MyApp',
            target: 'es5',
            exclude: [
                'node_modules',
                '**/*.d.ts'
            ],
            excludeExternals: true,
            externalPattern: '**/*/A.ts',
            excludePrivate: true,
            mode: 'file'
        },
        src: [
            ...some source...
        ]
    }
}
```

This config is working well. I have got a documentation without A.ts file. So now I need to put a few files, so I tried to put on `externalPattern` something like: `**/*/(A|B|C|D).ts` but without success (because during recompiling of documentation I had error: `Process terminated with code 3. 'B' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If I want to exclude externals files using `externalPattern` I should to write pattern something like that:

```
externalPattern: "**/*/{A,B,C,D}.ts"
```

> { } = allows for a comma-separated list of "or" expressions
>
> , = or

Useful for me was [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074740/8479567) from topic about regex in gruntfile.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/170#issuecomment-228983184), the right syntax would be `**/*/+(A|B|C|D).ts`.  Also, it looks like you are running into a problem with your shell trying to interpret the pipe characters, so try adding double quotes around the whole thing:

```
externalPattern: '"**/*/+(A|B|C|D).ts"'
```

Comment: I still get the "Process terminated with code 3. 'B' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." error